# I can only parse my mapStateToProps object to an extent inside of my react component

Tags: react-native, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I am pretty new to redux and am having trouble parsing JSON data, when I mapStateToProps inside my react component. For instance, if I console.log(this.props.chartData[0]) in my react component, the console will display the array I am trying to access, however, when I try to access a specific element in the array by console logging (this.props.ChartData[0].title), I get an error:

```
[enter image description here][1]



class ChartContainer extends Component {

    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.chartChanged();
    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.props.chartData[0]);
        return(
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
                test
            </Text>   
        );
    }
}



const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        chartData: state.chart
    }
};


export default connect (mapStateToProps, {chartChanged}) (ChartContainer);
```

Interestingly, I have no problem accessing(this.props.ChartData[0].title) inside my reducer.

```
import {CHART_CHANGED} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = { chartData: [] };

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
        console.log(action);

 switch (action.type) {
        case CHART_CHANGED:
            console.log("action");
            console.log(action.payload[0].title);
            return{...state, chartData: action.payload};
        default: 
            return state;
    }
};
```

Here is the api call in my action file:

```
export const chartChanged = (chartData) => {

return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
        .then((chartData) =>{
            dispatch({type: CHART_CHANGED, payload: chartData.data});
        });
    };
};
```

If someone can explain why this is happening, I would be super grateful.

Comment: is it logging an empty array?

Comment: No, it's logging undefined.

Comment: are you fetching the data from an API?

Comment: Yes, I am fetching from an API.

Comment: can you show me this console.log this.props.ChartData?

Comment: I think you need to fetch data like this.props.ChartData.charData[0].title?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that you shouldn't assign any value during fetching, what you need to do is use lodash and try doing something like this

```
import _ from 'lodash'

const title = _.get(this.props.ChartData, 'chartData', [])

if(!isFetching){
//do something
}
```